# Nox App Player for React Native Development

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

hello… has anyone achieved working with Nox App Player as the default android emulator in React Native? I've been using it with Nativescript… but I can't use it in React Native… (it's ah faster dev env for me)…

Once I run "react-native run-android" it builds but does not recognize Nox is existing and tells me that there is no emulator or device present...

Please help…

Comment: did you find any solutions

Comment: yeah... I will post below as an answer... :D

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/how-to-connect-android-studio-nox-app-t3241330
using this solution (with copying adb files to nox bin folder and then changing name from adb.exe to nox_adb.exe) I was able to install an apk to Nox player hovewer adb reverse doesn't work

Comment: okay, adb reverse doesn't work but you still can bring the dev menu while running app on Nox and then find your local address (ex. the one you are connected to wifi) in my case that was 192.168.1.192:8081 as Debug server host and port. notice that 127.0.0.1 won't work as app on Nox will try to connect to self

Comment: I posted the solution below… figured it out myself… after a while of suffering… XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer...

I used this tutorial... minus some instructions: http://www.jitblog.net/react-native-with-memu-emulator/

mine is:

- `react-native run-android`
- whether it says no device detected is actually ok
- install the debug apk on MeMu or Nox App Player (manually)
- `cls`
- `react-native start`
- on the dev settings of the app in the emulator: `[ip address]:8081`
- restart installed app multiple times until desired setup is achieved...

:D

Comment: I think not is using only KitKat ,  and I need  to test the app on latest OS

Comment: I assume you are talking about an actual device? :)

Comment: can you explain step 3: 'install the debug apk on MeMu or Nox App Player.' I installed Nox App Player but still get 'No Android device found'

Comment: it's ok to get no device detected… for me it works like using the wifi workflow described in the react native documentation…

Comment: you locate the built debug apk dir… manually install it on the emulator then setup the ip addresses… :)

Comment: can you post a small video step by step to do this?

Comment: hi, where can i find the dev settings of the app in the emulator? I am using nox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem with below  steps:

1-copy the adb file from Sdk/platform-tools to your desktop.

2-make 2 copy on your desktop with these names :

1- adb  2-nox_adb

3-then copy these files to your Nox setup location.

4-please confirm that alert for replacing and next restart your nox player

**You should turn on usb debuging in you nox setting**